# How many ordered pairs (A,B) are there so that they satisfy the condition $A\subseteq B$ , A and B are subsets of a set S with n elements?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many ordered pairs $(A,B)$ are there so that they satisfy the condition $A\subseteq B$ , where  $A\subseteq S$ and $B\subseteq S$, and $S$ has $n$ elements?

How to approach this question ?

If we start with $n$ elements then there will be $n$ subsets of size $1$, $1$ subset of size $0$ , $n-1$ subsets of size $n-1$ and each subset will have its own further subset ,which will also be a subset of given set $S$ , so now how to proceed from this stage ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution 1: Each element can either be (1) in neither $A$ nor $B$, (2) in only $B$, (3) in both $A$ and $B$, which makes three choices per element. Notice that you can treat each element independently, so the total number is $3^n$.

Solution 2: Let's fix $B$ and find the number of satisfying sets $A$. If $|B|=k$, then there are $2^k$ possible choices for $A$. Now let's sum over all choices of $B$. For each $k$, there are $\binom nk$ choices for $B$, each with $2^k$ choices for $A$, giving $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom nk 2^k$. Notice that if we rewrite this as $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom nk 2^k \cdot 1^{n-k}$, then this is exactly the binomial expansion of $(2+1)^n$.